# RAID + how to manipulate the disk size with RAID controller

Tags: raid, redhat, hard-drive

We have 3 Hadoop HDFS servers on DELL HW physical machines , when all servers are with RHEL 7.2 version

Each server include 3 HDFS disks when each disk is 1TB

Now we want to do add another 3 Hadoop servers with 3 disks per machine

The problem is that we not found 1TB disks , and what we can buy is only disks with 2TB

The Second problem is that when is dealing with HDFS disks , then all HDFS disks must be with the same size

Because the disks on the old servers can reached 100% use space while the new servers with the 3 disks of 2TB will be half of the used space

So basically all HDFS disks should be with the same size

So my Question is – can we manipulate by RAID the disks on the new servers , in way that Linux will identify the 2TB as 1TB disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t know much about Apache Hadoop. And I dont know much about **your** RAID setup, but even even if you have 2TB disks, you could juste manage the size in Linux directly using LVM or even simple partitions with fdisk.

I would just make sure I have the same amount of space to mimic your other machine. You can go as far as setting the same numbers of block per partition as you have on your other disks if that is needed.

I would suggest you do a lab with LVM disk management. There are plenty of tutorials out there about LVM.

Here is a good documentation to start with if you need it. It's from RedHat and it is for version 7.x.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lvm_overview